# HTTPSBOOT Failed to initialize network connection

Tags: windows, bios, dell-inspiron

I have Dell Inspiron 3511 running Windows 11. On startup it started showing suddenly,

> Inspiron 3511 "HTTPSBOOT Failed to initialize network connection"

It doesn't boot now. I tried changing the boot sequence, but I can only see Uefi HTTPs Boot (Placeholder) in my boot sequence, so there is no option of changing the sequence.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/Latitude-5320-switching-to-HTTPSBoot-at-random/td-p/7854872

We have encountered the issue as well when (1) laptop is in sleep mode, and/or (2) if the laptop goes idle for a certain period and we also clueless on how to resolve it.

However, I'm not sure if this is the solution but one of our users encountered the error this morning and i went ahead to meet up with him.  First thought that is that the laptop always boots to HTTPS instead of the SSD regardless how many times I restart it, so I when to the BIOS and checked the Boot sequence.

Upon checking, the 1st boot sequence was set to the HTTPS (or the network card) followed by the SSD.  I've unticked the "HTTPS" or the network card and saved the settings, restarted the laptop and it was able to boot to Windows.  I've shut down the laptop several times and even put it to sleep mode while walking around (while carrying the laptop) and so far no issues with the HTTPS.

Btw, we are using the company OS image and we set the laptop to AHCI instead of RAID.